# Static content is not getting loaded with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am breaking my head with this issue. I have a simple controller class with the capability to render a simple html page along with the Spring boot initializer class.

I have placed the HTML page in the static folder under src/main/resources directory. 
But I am not able to get the html page. Instead I get 404 error.

Below is the structure of my project

[image: Project structure]

Below is my Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Below are the controller and Spring Initializer class

DemoApplication.java:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

SimpleController.java:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SimpleController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(){
    System.out.println("Hello Home...");
    return "home";
}
}
```

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
 Helloooo......
 </body>
</html>
```

Console Logs on running the Spring Boot:

:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2017-02-28 10:46:26.676  INFO 8240 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on abc with PID 8240 (C:\SpringBootEx\demo\target\classes started by abc in C:\SpringBootEx\demo)
2017-02-28 10:46:26.681  INFO 8240 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-02-28 10:46:26.771  INFO 8240 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@70b0b186: startup date [Tue Feb 28 10:46:26 MST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-28 10:46:28.281  INFO 8240 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-28 10:46:28.514  INFO 8240 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-28 10:46:28.949  INFO 8240 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-02-28 10:46:28.973  INFO 8240 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-02-28 10:46:28.974  INFO 8240 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-02-28 10:46:29.194  INFO 8240 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-02-28 10:46:29.194  INFO 8240 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2428 ms
2017-02-28 10:46:29.448  INFO 8240 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-02-28 10:46:29.455  INFO 8240 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-02-28 10:46:29.457  INFO 8240 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-02-28 10:46:29.458  INFO 8240 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-02-28 10:46:29.458  INFO 8240 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-02-28 10:46:29.967  INFO 8240 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@70b0b186: startup date [Tue Feb 28 10:46:26 MST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-28 10:46:30.071  INFO 8240 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.controller.SimpleController.home()
2017-02-28 10:46:30.080  INFO 8240 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-02-28 10:46:30.081  INFO 8240 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-02-28 10:46:30.145  INFO 8240 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-28 10:46:30.145  INFO 8240 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-28 10:46:30.194  INFO 8240 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-02-28 10:46:30.478  INFO 8240 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-02-28 10:46:30.582  INFO 8240 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-02-28 10:46:30.590  INFO 8240 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 4.391 seconds (JVM running for 5.147)
2017-02-28 10:49:04.176  INFO 8240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-02-28 10:49:04.176  INFO 8240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-02-28 10:49:04.205  INFO 8240 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 29 ms
Hello Home...

Can someone please help me in getting the view rendered? Thanks..

Comment: Show us your controller where you call the view. Your screenshot shows the view outside the static folder ... so I am a little confused.

Comment: Your **home.html** file is not within the **src/main/resources/static** folder but in the **src/main/resources** folder, put it in the folder like you mentioned and it should work.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried placing the home.html page inside the static folder too..  But still I see the same issue.

Comment: Added additional information including the controller class code and the html.Uploaded the correct project structure too.

Comment: Put home.html in `src/main/resources/templates`

Comment: @MarcTarin - I tried that too. But that too is not working..

Comment: @Saravana6788 My bad, I had overlooked you pom.xml. `src/main/resources/templates` is the default path for thymeleaf, but you're not using it. What happens if you add the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf to your pom.xml and leave home.html in `src/main/resources/templates`?

Comment: @marc  - in that case it works. But i dont want to use any template like thymeleaf or freemarker or jsp as it is a simple static html page. Is that not possible?

Comment: @Saravana6788 I've always used the thymeleaf + html templates, so I cannot guarantee anything, but I'd try `src/main/resources/public` as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place home.html into one of the following locations:

> src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/home.html
>
> src/main/resources/resources/home.html
>
> src/main/resources/static/home.html
>
> src/main/resources/public/home.html

and make

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    System.out.println("Hello Home...");
    return "home.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the below tags inside <build></build>

 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
 <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
        </resources>`
    </build>
```